# How running second worker, during the first worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a table with two columns `foo` and `bar`, and I have a sidekiq worker who records objects in `foo`, as well as second worker who takes objects from `foo` converts them and put to `bar`.

Second worker starts after successful completion of first worker, but I want to run it after few second as start first daemon.That they work at the *same time*.

I trying use a `sidekiq-superworker`  gem, and do this

```
Superworker.define(:MySuperworker) do
  FirstWorker do
    SecondWorker
  end
end
```

but second worker was start after full complete first worker, how to do this?

Comment: Why you don't merge both the worker logics in single? You can't make sure that 2 workers will run in parallel always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jobs are asynchronous so you can't control exactly when they run but you can control when you create them:

```
class FirstWorker
  def perform
    # create foo
    SecondWorker.perform_async(...)
    # do more work
  end
end
```